# Get a specific value from a specific array when having two dropdown lists

Tags: c#, arrays, drop-down-menu

I have 5 arrays which represents 1 city each. Each position in the array represents the distance to another city (all arrays shares the same position for each specific city). And I have two dropdown lists from where the user is supposed to select two cities to calculate the distance between them. 
It's set up like this:

```
    //                City0, City1, City2, City3, City4
    int[] distanceFromCity0 = { 0, 16, 39, 9, 24 };
    int[] distanceFromCity1 = { 16, 0, 36, 32, 54 };
    int[] distanceFromCity2 = { 39, 36, 0, 37, 55 };
    int[] distanceFromCity3 = { 9, 32, 37, 0, 21 };
    int[] distanceFromCity4 = { 24, 54, 55, 21, 0 };

    int cityOne = Convert.ToInt16(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
    int cityTwo = Convert.ToInt16(DropDownList2.SelectedValue);
```

And within the dropdown lists each city has the corresponding ID (city0 = 0, city1 = 1 etc)

I have tried a few different ways, but none of them really works.
So basically, how do I "connect" DropDownList1 to one of the arrays depending on the choice, and then connecting DropDownList2 to one of the positions in the selected array (from DropDownList1 selection) and print it out to Label1?
Is it easier with a 2D array?

This probably looks easy for you, but I'm a noob in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to combine `distanceFromCity0` ... `distanceFromCity4` into a single 2D array and use the two cities as indexes to the distance value:

```
int[][] distanceBetweenCities = {
    new[]{ 0, 16, 39, 9, 24 },
    new[]{ 16, 0, 36, 32, 54 },
    new[]{ 39, 36, 0, 37, 55 },
    new[]{ 9, 32, 37, 0, 21 },
    new[]{ 24, 54, 55, 21, 0 }
};

int cityOne = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
int cityTwo = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList2.SelectedValue);
var distance = distanceBetweenCities[cityOne][cityTwo];
```

Comment: What does "new[]" do? Can't I just do it like

{ { 0, 16, 39, 9, 24} , { 16, 0, 36, 32, 54 } , { 39, 36, 0, 37, 55 } , { 9, 32, 37, 0, 21 } , { 24, 54, 55, 21, 0 } } ?

Comment: It's shorthand for `new int[] { ... }`. The compiler doesn't need the `int` as it already knows the type. You may specify it if it makes the code clearer to you though. Try it like ` { { 0, 16, 39, 9, 24} , { 16, 0, 36, 32, 54 }...` and see what happens. (Hint, it'll give an error as the `new` is required. It's what the compiler wants... :)

Comment: How do I print this out? It returns error `Cannot implicity convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label'`
The name `distance`has a blue error line beneath it saying something like (it's not in English) `cannot assign method group to an implicitly typed local variable`.

I also tried to convert `distance`to string, but I receive the same `System.Web...`error when using it instead.

Comment: @NightWalker you want to assign to `label.Text`, rather than `label`

Comment: Ah, what was I thinking?! I should've seen that :P Thanks for pointing it out. I got really confused.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using two-dimensional array is very easy. You can regard it like a matrix. Some code like below:

```
int[,] distanceMatrix = new int[5, 5] {   { 0, 16, 39, 9, 24 },
                                            { 16, 0, 36, 32, 54 },
                                            { 39, 36, 0, 37, 55 },
                                            { 9, 32, 37, 0, 21 },
                                            { 24, 54, 55, 21, 0 }
                                        };
int cityOne = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
int cityTwo = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList2.SelectedValue);
var distance = distanceMatrix[cityOne, cityTwo]; //the distance between cityOne and cityTwo;
```

Comment: Does `new int[5, 5]`do the same thing as having `new[]` before every sub-array as in the code provided by David Arno? As I said, I'm a noob so if you could explain it to me it would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: David Arno's array is a Jagged Array. A jagged array is an array whose elements are arrays.  The elements of a jagged array can be of different dimensions and sizes. A jagged array is sometimes called an "array of arrays."  What I wrote is a Multidimensional Array. Arrays can have more than one dimension, like a matrix.